# SSL Cert for weblogic

Tags: ssl, weblogic

I have been shared a certificate by the Apps Team, which is using my application installed in Weblogic. How I decide that it needs to import on Identity or Trust KeyStore?

Comment: Get the confirmation from your app team that the certificate will be used by the application to make a https connection to another application. 
If so, the certificate should be stored in the Identity store.

Comment: If you've only been given a public certificate, then chances are it's meant to be installed in the trust store.  That certificate (or certificates signed by that certificate) would be used by client applications that connect to your weblogic server using 2 way ssl.  

An identity certificate used by your weblogic server would also need an associated private key, so you would need a keystore that contained both the public certificate and private key in that case.